# OutOfMemoryException with RestSharp downloading big files

Tags: restsharp

I've got an OutOfMemoryException using RestSharp when I downloading a big sized files ( 1GB ). After reading some papers seems the cause of it could be that RestSharp is using internally the class HttpWebRequest. Here's some explanation http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908573 ( cause -> This issue occurs because the .NET Framework buffers the outgoing data by default when you use the HttpWebRequest class. )

My question is about if it's possible with RestSharp download this sort of files or I must looking for other options. I've tryed several combination with code, but I do not find the correct way for doing only with RestSharp API.